# javascript warning message for value field

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to make a javascript that will show a warning message for some specific words from a textfield. I mean if a user write **http://** and **/** in a `textfield` and click on the Submit button of my form then a javascript will show a error message to the user. So how I can do it for this textfield:

```
<input type="text" name="attn" size="35" />
```

How I should edit it?

Comment: If you don't mind [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) I would look in to the [validate add-on](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: Make sure that you check this client-side and server-side. Bypassing client-side validation checks is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Give the input some `id`

Then you could do:

```
var the_input = document.getElementById('inputID');
the_input.onkeyup = function(){
    if(the_input.value == 'http://' || the_input.value.indexOf('http://') > 0) {
       alert('AHHH!');
       the_input.value = '';
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rdZAZ/

Try typing `http://` into the input.

Answer (score 1):

When the user submits the form, you could perform the following:

```
//Grab the value of your textbox
var textValue = document.getElementsByName("myInput").value;

//Checks if the textbox contains 'http://' or '/'
if(textValue.indexOf('http://') || textValue.indexOf('/'))
{
    alert("Please check your input and try again..."); 
    return false;
}
```